# How do I save a Dask Array as a stack of images?

Tags: python, numpy, dask, scikit-image

I have a Dask array of image data.  How do I save this array to a directory of tiff files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally there would be some sort of `imsave` function.  As of 2019-10-31 I can't find one, but you might want to watch https://image.dask.org in the future for this sort of functionality.

You can accomplish this today using map_blocks and skimage.io.imread

```
import dask.array as da
import skimage.io

x = da.random.random((2000, 2000), chunks=(200, 200))  # make a dask array

def save_file(arr, block_info=None):
    """ Save file to foo-x-y.tif, where x and y are block locations """
    filename = "foo-" + "-".join(map(str, block_info[0]["chunk-location"])) + ".tif"
    skimage.io.imsave(filename, arr)
    return arr

x.map_blocks(save_file, dtype=x.dtype).compute()       # call function on every block
```

.

```
$ ls
foo-0-0.tif
foo-0-1.tif
...
foo-9-8.tif
foo-9-9.tif
```